# How to connect to local API created by using PHP from Vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, vue-resource

I've created a small API using Slim Framework (PHP) and I want to connect to it from my Vue.js application. How can I do this? I keep my API in Open Server. Path: http://localhost/restapi.loc/api/customers. Via this path I can easily get my data in browser. But what about the Vue.js app?
Here's my API:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

$app->get('/api/customers', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
  $db = new DB();
  $db = $db->Connect();

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM workers";
  $result = $db->query($sql);

  return json_encode($result->fetch_assoc());

  $db->close();
});
```

That's the way how I'm trying to reach the API:

```
getCustomers() {
      this.$http.get('http://localhost/restapi.loc/api/customers')
        .then(function(response){
          console.log(JSON.parse(response.body));
        });
    }
```

But it doesn't work. I'd really appreciate every response from your side.

Comment: Check the `Network` tab in your browser's developer tools. What response are you getting back from the server?

Comment: Whats just `console.log(response);` show? also are you including [vue-resource](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource)? `$db->close();` is useless, and perhaps you should be returning `return $response->withJson()` and calling `fetch_assoc()` once will only return the first row.

Comment: @craig_h I forgot to attach the responce, my fault. I'm getting "Not found" error.

Comment: @craig_h Is it a correct way to get date from the local API?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone console.log(response) shows this: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone in the browser if I call my API directly the API works absolutely correct.